# How to refactor Android package name in Android Studio, to multiple words separated by periods/dots?

Tags: android-studio, refactoring

I want to rename a project’s package name (Android) from e.g:

com.company.title

To:

com.company.title.more.words

But Android Studio’s Refactoring is only using the last word, so I end up with:

com.company.words

Can anyone help?

Comment: @YQadoome this has nothing what so ever to do with naming **conventions** - this has to do with a refactoring issue of the package name